# How to start a new activity when an image is swiped to right

Tags: android

I have an image view in my splash screen and i want to start my main activity when the splash screen is swiped to the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a gesture detector and onSwipe right create intent to start mainActivity. You can read about gesture detector in below link.

http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html

In onFling you check if flinged right or left.

http://www.sitepoint.com/android-gestures-and-touch-mechanics/